# How to limit search only to file name instead the content of files?

Tags: search, server.app

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching by file name (as opposed to name and contents) in Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/searching-by-file-name-as-opposed-to-name-and-contents-in-lion)

I have a "server" with OS X Lion and a shared hard disk, and some clients with various version of OS X (10.4 to 10.7).

When a client search for a file, I would like to limit the search to the **file name** and **not the content** of the files.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in the Finder, hit Command + F. Notice under the Search: bar there's some options. Use the pulldown to select Name. Then set the next to Matches, Contains... and type in your search string.